# Datacontext Not Reflected in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hokkay...

So I'm certain I'm just doing wrong something fairly rudimentary but, for whatever, when I change the value in my class, the datacontext stores the right value but the value is not sent to the textblock.

```
namespace Points_Calculator
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        private PointsModel Model = new PointsModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Model;
        }

        private void Process()
        {
            if(Model.ValidInput())
            {
                double K = Model.Kcal / Denum.Kcal;
                double F = Model.Fat / Denum.Fat;
                double A = Math.Round(K + F);

                //outPoints.Text = A.ToString() + " Points";
                Model.Points = A.ToString() + " Points";
            }
        }

        private void inputFat_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Process();
        }

        private void inputKcal_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Process();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in Process(). See where I commented out the bit about changing the Text property of outPoints (TextBlock)? That works fine. But I want to use the databinding, which is the next line. The correct value is set in Model.Points, as it should, but for some reason, it is not reflected in the TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock Name="outPoints" Text="{Binding Points, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   Margin="0,20,-25,0"
                   FontSize="16"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   TextAlignment="Center"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I would really appreciated it.

Edit: Many thanks to Decoherence for the advice and for those who have the same problem, I'm linking the relevant
[How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx) page.

Comment: Your `PointsModel` has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and the setter of the `Points`property should call `NotifyPropertyChanged`, so the problem is actually with your `PointsModel` which your are not showing.

Comment: @decoherence Thank you very much. That was the missing piece; I didn't even realize that, which is why I didn't include the PointsModel. It is now working superbly. Again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PointsModel` has to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and the setter of the `Points` property should call `NotifyPropertyChanged`, so the problem is actually with your `PointsModel`.